# Pandera Python: Use DataFrameModel for validating multiindex columns

Tags: python, pandas, pydantic, pandera

I'm trying to validate a multiindex dataframe with DataFrameModel

```py
import pandera as pa
from pandera import Column, DataFrameSchema, Index
from pandera.typing import Index, Series

Test dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        ("here", "state"): ["NY", "FL", "GA", "CA"],
        ("here", "city"): ["New York", "Miami", "Atlanta", "San Francisco"],
        ("here", "price"): [8, 12, 10, 16],
    }
)
```

```py
When i use:

zone_validator = DataFrameSchema(
    {
        ("here", "state"): Column(str),
        ("here", "price"): Column(int),
    }
)

zone_validator.validate(df)
print(df)
```

All is fine, but, when i use this like the documentation (https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataframe_models.html#multiindex), gives to me an error.

```py
class MultiIndexSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    state: Series[str]
    city: Series[str]
    price: Series[int]

    class Config:
        # provide multi index options in the config
        multiindex_name = "here"
        multiindex_strict = True
        multiindex_coerce = True


schema = MultiIndexSchema
schema.validate(df)
```

```py
 raise schema_error from original_exc
pandera.errors.SchemaError: column 'state' not in dataframe

   here                     
  state           city price
0    NY       New York     8
1    FL          Miami    12
2    GA        Atlanta    10
3    CA  San Francisco    16
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what error? We can't run your code and we can't read in your mind. You have to show all details in question (as text, not image, not link to external portal)

Comment: raise schema_error from original_exc
pandera.errors.SchemaError: column 'state' not in dataframe
   here                     
  state           city price
0    NY       New York     8
1    FL          Miami    12
2    GA        Atlanta    10
3    CA  San Francisco    16

Just run the snipe code.

Comment: put this in question, not in comments

Answer (score 0):

You try to use a multiindex index for multiindex columns. Try using field aliases like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import Series

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        ("here", "state"): ["NY", "FL", "GA", "CA"],
        ("here", "city"): ["New York", "Miami", "Atlanta", "San Francisco"],
        ("here", "price"): [8, 12, 10, 16],
    }
)


class MultiIndexSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    here_state: Series[str] = pa.Field(alias=("here", "state"))
    here_city: Series[str] = pa.Field(alias=("here", "city"))
    here_price: Series[int] = pa.Field(alias=("here", "price"))


schema = MultiIndexSchema
schema.validate(df)
```